# Fitting issues when including certain combination of variables with lavaan::cfa()

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am trying to fit 13 ordinal indicator variables to a single factor, but there are three of them that will result in a warning when they're included simultaneously. You can find the code below (data is at the end of the code block).

```
library(lavaan)
c("q0069_0001","q0069_0002","q0069_0003","q0069_0004","q0069_0005",
  "q0069_0006","q0069_0007","q0069_0008","q0069_0009","q0069_0010",
  "q0069_0011","q0069_0012","q0069_0013") -> q.sexrisk

# Works fine:
'SexRisk =~ q0069_0001+q0069_0002+q0069_0003+q0069_0004+q0069_0005+q0069_0006+q0069_0007+q0069_0008+q0069_0009+q0069_0010+q0069_0011+q0069_0012' -> my.model
my.sem01 <- cfa(my.model, data = my.data, ordered = c(q.sexrisk))

# Warning:
'SexRisk =~ q0069_0001+q0069_0002+q0069_0003+q0069_0004+q0069_0005+q0069_0006+q0069_0007+q0069_0008+q0069_0009+q0069_0010+q0069_0011+q0069_0012+q0069_0013' -> my.model
my.sem02 <- cfa(my.model, data = my.data, ordered = c(q.sexrisk))

# Warning message:
# In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
#  lavaan WARNING:
#    The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
#    does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
#    (= 2.974964e-17) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the
#    model is not identified.

# Isolated to these three:
'SexRisk =~ q0069_0010+q0069_0011+q0069_0013' -> my.model
my.sem03 <- cfa(my.model, data = my.data, ordered = c(q.sexrisk))

# Warning message:
# In lav_model_vcov(lavmodel = lavmodel, lavsamplestats = lavsamplestats,  :
#   lavaan WARNING:
#     The variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters (vcov)
#     does not appear to be positive definite! The smallest eigenvalue
#     (= 4.185020e-17) is close to zero. This may be a symptom that the
#     model is not identified.

structure(list(q0069_0001 = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "4", "3", "2", "4", "1", "5", "2", "1", 
"3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "3", "2", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "4", "4", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "2", "1", "2", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "3", "4", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "3", "4", "1", "2", "1", "4", "4", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "2", "1", "3", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", 
"1", "3", "2", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"2", "4", "2", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "4", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "2", "3", "4", "3", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", 
"4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "4", "3", 
"2", "4", "4", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", "3", "4", 
"4", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "4", "1", "2", "3", "1", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"3", "2", "2", "4", "1", "3", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "2", 
"2", "4", "3", "2", "1", "4", "2", "4", "3", "1"), q0069_0002 = c("1", 
"2", "1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "4", "4", "2", "2", "4", "2", "3", 
"2", "4", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "2", "4", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2", 
"1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", 
"3", "4", "2", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "3", 
"2", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "4", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "2", "4", "4", "1", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", "2", "4", "3", "1", "3", "4", "2", 
"2", "2", "4", "3", "2", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", 
"2", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "2", "4", "4", "2", 
"4", "1", "3", "1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "4", "3", "3", "4", 
"2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "4", "2", "4", "2", "1", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "4", "4", "2", "1", "4", "4", "3", "3", "1", "3", "4", "2", 
"3", "4", "1", "3", "2", "1", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", 
"2", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "3", "4", "1", "3", "1", 
"4", "2", "2", "2", "4", "3", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "2", 
"1", "4", "1"), q0069_0003 = c("1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"2", "2", "2", "4", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", 
"2", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "4", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), q0069_0004 = c("2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "2", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", 
"4", "2", "1", "2", "4", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "2", "3", "3", 
"4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "2", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "2", "1"), q0069_0005 = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", 
"1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), q0069_0006 = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"4", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), q0069_0007 = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "2", "4", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1"), q0069_0008 = c("1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), q0069_0009 = c("1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "4", "2", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "4", "4", 
"3", "1", "4", "1", "1", "4", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "4", "1", "2", 
"3", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "2", "4", "2", "1", "4", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "3", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "1", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "4", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "3", "1"), q0069_0010 = c("1", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "4", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"2", "1", "1", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "4", 
"4", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "2", 
"1", "4", "3", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"4", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", "2", "1", "3", "3", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "1", "3", "3", "2", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "5", "2", "2", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "1"), q0069_0011 = c("1", "2", "4", "3", "2", "2", 
"1", "4", "4", "2", "1", "4", "4", "4", "1", "4", "1", "4", "4", 
"4", "1", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "4", "4", 
"4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"4", "1", "1", "4", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", "4", "4", 
"4", "1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "4", "3", 
"1", "4", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"4", "1", "4", "3", "1", "4", "4", "2", "2", "5", "4", "2", "1", 
"4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1", "3", "4", 
"3", "2", "4", "4", "1", "3", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "4", 
"3", "4", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "3", "2", "1", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "4", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1"), q0069_0012 = c("1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "2", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", 
"3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1"), q0069_0013 = c("1", "1", "4", "2", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "2", "1", "1", 
"4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "2", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"1", "1", "1", "4", "1", "3", "4", "3", "2", "5", "3", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "4", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "4", "4", 
"3", "2", "3", "4", "1", "4", "4", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "3", 
"3", "4", "4", "3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "1", 
"1", "4", "5", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
251L)) -> my.data
```

From what I could find on this error, other questions on this site and elsewhere mention that this could be an issue of colinearity, but looking at contingency tables of the offending variables shows they're pretty different. [This paper](http://www.ssicentral.com/lisrel/techdocs/ordinal.pdf) also mentions that the assumption of a latent multivariate normal distribution might be a poor fit for some data.

It's interesting to note that despite the warning, a seemingly reasonable fit is still returned. I'd like to know if the warning means these estimates shouldn't be trusted and what to do about it (perhaps comparing measures of fit and dropping the worst performing item?).

EDIT: I've also read that additional variables can fix this type of issues. In fact, I plan to do use this LV for a larger model with other covariates. Trying an `age` variable just now made the error go away. Does this mean I should not be concerned about the warnings for the CFA if everything works fine for the full model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Structural equation modeling relies on means and the variance covariance matrix. For ordinal data, the software will calculate polychoric correlations to try to recover the relation between the categorical indicators under the assumption that they are polychotomized realizations of continuous variables. And these continuous variables are multivariate normal.

In calculating these correlations, it computes them in a pairwise manner (between every two items). This can easily result in a situation where variable A has a correlation with variable B and variable C that instantly defines limits on the possible correlation between B and C. But when the correlation between B and C is computed, it falls outside of this range. This will create a non positive definite correlation matrix with (near) zero or negative eigenvalues.

You may be able to use the ridge option in lavaan to regularize the solution. This may solve this problem. Alternatively, you can use software that calculates the polychoric correlation matrix all at once (like EQS) instead of in pairwise fashion. This is less likely to lead to this problem. There are some other solutions in the literature.

You could also estimate the model as a Bayesian multilevel model. An ordinal CFA is identical to the 2-PL item response theory model described in the Stan reference manual. However you lose the goodness of fit indices that are pre-programmed into SEM software.